# Bitwise on negative numbers

Tags: c

Here is a bitwise operation on a negative number:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int a = -20, b = 84;
    printf("%d", (a>>(a &b)));
}
```

Two's complement of -20 is `1100` in binary, and 84 is `10000100`. So `a & b` should be `100`, but the answer is 68 and the overall answer is -2.

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 5):

-20 is not 1100<sub>2</sub>. It's most likely (if ints are 32-bit and we're not talking odd platforms), 11111111111111111111111111101100<sub>2</sub>.

84 is not 10000100<sub>2</sub>. It is 1010100<sub>2</sub>.

ANDing them together:

```
11111111111111111111111111101100
&
00000000000000000000000001010100
=
00000000000000000000000001000100 (68 decimal)
```

And then you're shifting -20 right 68 positions, which has 2 issues:

- right shifts of negative integers are implementation defined, what's your compiler's implementation?
- shifts by the number of bits in the value or by more than that result in undefined behavior

128-bit ints are unlikely on common platforms. 64-bit ints are rare, but not impossible, but for them 68 >= 64 and so you should get undefined behavior.

Now, what this undefined behavior may look like...

If our ints are 32-bit and we're doing this on the x86 platform (or something sufficiently similar), 68 should get truncated by the CPU to 5 bits, leaving you with the shift count of 68 & 31 = 4.

And then, assuming the `SAR` instruction (sign-preserving arithmetic shift right) is used for `>>`, we get (-20) SAR 4 = -2:

```
11111111111111111111111111101100
SAR
4
=
11111111111111111111111111111110 (-2 decimal)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Windows, it should come with a calculator app which has support for binary.
That is a good reliable source for calculations.
In that you can select `Word` which is an int.

Negitive numbers are noted in memory by all the bit's on the left side being 1. so -20 is

```
  1111-1111-1110-1100
= 0xFFEC
```

And 84 is:

```
  0000-0000-0101-0100
= 0x0054
```

And is a bitwise operation that compares the two passed numbers checking each bit. If both bits are 1, the resulting bit is 1. Otherwise it is zero. So

```
  1111-1111-1110-1100
& 0000-0000-0101-0100
= 0000-0000-0100-0100
= 68
```